# QT TableView - Show Icons

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtgui

I'm having problems,  show Qicon in rows.

now:

[image]

I would like to show:

[image]

my code. But the icon does not appear and there is no compiler error:

```
c

lass MySubClassedSqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
      {
          Q_OBJECT
          public:
             MySubClassedSqlTableModel(QObject * parent = 0, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
             : QSqlTableModel(parent,db) {;}
             QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const
             {
                if(role==Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
                {
                   const QVariant value(data(index,Qt::DisplayRole));

                                       if(value.toString()=="yes"){
                                          return QIcon(":/img/icons/yes.png");
                                       }else{
                                          return QIcon(":/img/icons/no.png");
                                       }
                }
                return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
             }
      };
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem seems to be in your understanding of all the `Qt::ItemDataRoles`

You should change your code to return `QIcon` for `Qt::DecorationRole`, not for `Qt::BackgroundColorRole`

```
            if(role==Qt::DecorationRole)
            {
               const QVariant value(data(index,Qt::DisplayRole));

                                   if(value.toString()=="yes"){
                                      return QIcon(":/img/icons/yes.png");
                                   }else{
                                      return QIcon(":/img/icons/no.png");
                                   }
            }
            return QSqlTableModel::data(index,role);
```

Comment: And to do both? I need the background color and the icon. could help me?

Comment: please could show how to implement code in Qt::DecorationRole and QT::BackgroundColorRole? :)

Comment: By asking that question, you're implying that you don't really understand the code you've written or the Model-View architecture as a whole. I suggest you read the documentation, and more specifically [the purpose of item roles](http://qt-project.org/doc/model-view-programming.html#item-roles)